# Setting background on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to set a background on a notfication on Android wear however I get the error

> setBackground in
>   android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.WearableExtender cannot be
>   applied to (int)

I've been trying to figure it out for a while but I'm stumped.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Code Received")
            .setContentText("Your Orange Wednesday code is " + orangeCode)
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setBackground(R.drawable.orangebg));
```

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As can be seen in the documentation the method needs a bitmap as input.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setBackground(android.graphics.Bitmap)

> public NotificationCompat.WearableExtender setBackground (**Bitmap
>   background**)
>
> Set a background image to be displayed behind the notification
>   content. Contrary to the NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle, this
>   background will work with any notification style.
>
> Parameters
>
> **background - the background bitmap**

R.drawable.XXX is an integer identifier for the framework to find your physical asset. Use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.XXX)` to retrieve the bitmap from your assets and apply it later.